# How to use pandas .describe()

Tags: python, pandas

I have used pandas in the past but I have recently run into a problem where my code is not displaying the .head() or the .describe() function. I have copied my code below from another website and it is still not displaying. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.1f}".format

training_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="california_housing_train.csv")

training_df["median_house_value"] /= 1000.0


training_df.describe(include = 'all')
```

Comment: Did you forget to print it? `print(training_df.describe(include = 'all').to_string())`

Comment: The only idea I have is a bit naive: are you printing the output of both `.head()` and `.describe()`. Is common to skip using `print` when using a Jupyter Notebook for example, but you need to print the values when you're in an editor or something similar.

Comment: Yep that's it thanks for your help. I was using in jupitur and it would do it automatically. Now using Pycharm so that's my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer will work in a notebook or REPL, but doesn't actually print. Make sure to call the `print()` function to output while running.